# Pasar parámetros de un controlador a otro controlador via POST en C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

tengo que pasar parámetros de un controlador a otro, lo hacia con RedirectToAction() pero solo funciona cuando es HttpGet y necesito hacerlo con HttpPost, hay alguna manera de hacerlo? lo quiero con post porque no quiero que los parámetros se vean en la url. Gracias

```
 public ActionResult Search(int applicationId)
 {
   return RedirectToAction("EditBankTransfer", "Transfer", new{applicationId = applicationId});
 }
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditBankTransfer(int applicationId = 0){
 }
```

Comment: A ver que me aclare, ¿quieres que el usuario desde el navegador haga post hacia otra URL de tu servidor?

Comment: En realidad cuando el usuario haga un registro mediante POST en el controlador Search se evalua el parametro para mandar a otro controlador EditBankTransfer y este realiza una tarea diferente era HttpGet y funciona pero los parametros se ven en la url y eso es lo que no quiero, o hay alguno otra forma?? esas es mi duda basicamente

Comment: ¿Y no puedes usar TempData?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes llamar directamente la función

```
public ActionResult Search(int applicationId)
 {
   return EditBankTransfer(applicationId);
 }

 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditBankTransfer(int applicationId = 0){
 }
```